# Remove redundant CSS properties between 2 or more CSS files

Tags: html, css, diff

I have 2 CSS files that have redundant CSS properties set between them.

For example, in `foo.css`:

```
#test {
    border: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

in `bar.css`:

```
#test {
    border: 0;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: auto;
}
```

With this, I'd want to remove `border: 0;` from `bar.css`.

I expected to easily find an answer to this in an existing question, but for the life of me I couldn't find anything.  There must be some quick tool to do process 2 or more files?

Comment: open both files in notepad++ and compare..( manual way )

Comment: it's not good to put different attributes for the same object in different files. you should instead of deleting border, move all to only one file

Comment: diEcho: I even have Beyond Compare but was looking for a more automated way than doing it manually.

Comment: arial: I'm using CSS Media Queries to add additional styles to format my site for mobile which is why it is split across 2 files.

Comment: @TMC: You can use [CSS media queries in a single CSS file](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) which will be a minor optimisation.

Comment: @Marcel: Thanks for the tip, but even if I do that, I still  have the current problem of duplicate styles I need to get rid of first.

Answer (score 0):

There's an add-on for Firefox called [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) which scans the stylesheets on a page and gives you a list of the ones which are used and aren't used.

This can be useful for detecting which styles you can safely get rid of. (though you do still need to put some intelligence into it, as there might be some styles which show up as unused but are used dynamically, etc)

Answer (score 0):

chrome's extensions !

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/remove%20unused%20css?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

I hope it is usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool: [github.com/ruilisi/css-checker](https://github.com/ruilisi/css-checker).

It can automatically detect your similar CSS classes and show the diff between them. It can also parse your HTML or js files and find unused css classes.

#### To Install:

##### Using Go

```
go install github.com/ruilisi/css-checker@latest
```

(With go version before 1.17, use `go get github.com/ruilisi/css-checker`). Or download from [releases](https://github.com/ruilisi/css-checker/releases)

##### Using npm

```
npm install -g css-checker-kit
```

#### To Run

- `cd PROJECT_WITH_CSS_FILES` and just run:

```
css-checker
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31184158)